# Angular.js On-Demand Warning Messages

Tags: angularjs

I want to implement some on-demand warning messages to my login page, like when you type your username site immidiately warn users "checking.. this username is already using". How can i do this with Angular.js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ng-change](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angChange) directive on an input will let you know when the model is changing.
In the handler function you call the server's api, through the [$http service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) it'll return wether the username is in use or not. And you just show it with some [magic binding](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angBind).

Good developing, if you have further question regarding this application. SHOW US CODE!

UI Bootstrap's [typeahead directive](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) may give you a jumpstart.

Comment: How can i implement this feature (on-demand warnings/alerts) into my code ?

http://s24.postimg.org/n83252r6t/bookmarkstackoverflowi_in.jpg

When i type "aaa", site must ignore it and simply return a on-demand message near the label like that "aaa is not a valid URL"

Comment: <div modal="editmark">
+    <div class="modal-header">
+      <h4>Bookmark Editor</h4>
+    </div>
+    <div class="modal-body">
+      <form class="form-horizontal" name="EditBookmarkForm">
+        <div class="control-group">
+          <label class="control-label">Title</label>
+          <div class="controls">
+            <input type="text" placeholder="Awesome website" ng-model="curmark.title" ng-required />
+          </div>
+        </div>
+        <div class="control-group">
+          <label class="control-label">URL</label>

Comment: In this case write a custom formatter (validator), where you check the url and toggle field model to invalid.

Check the documentation for guidance:
http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#customvalidation
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController